# Change CSS with Javascript not working

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want the text inside the input tag to change colors when the text length reaches a certain amount. If I use jquery, it works perfectly. Why wont this work with pure javascript?

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function count(x){      
                var size = x.length;    
                document.getElementById("show_length").innerHTML = size;

                if(size > 5){
                    //$("#name").css({"color":"blue"});
                    document.getElementById("name").style.color = "blue";                   
                } else {
                    //$("#name").css({"color":"red"});                  
                    document.getElementById("name").style.color = "red";    
                }   
            }

        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input type="text" name="name" id="name" autofocus maxlength="50" onkeyup="count(this.value)">
        <span id="show_length">0</span>/50 *Name must be greater than 5 characters
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Because it has to be `document`, not `documument` :)

Comment: Learn to use your console! Error is clear as day when you look at the error message in the console.

Comment: I have been studying this for like 30 minutes. Thanks! Ill go back back to school and learn to spell... :(

Comment: @John 30m and already on SO? Your IDE or Console should have told you about your error already. `Uncaught ReferenceError: documument is not defined`

Comment: yep you have to learn to use your console, check [this](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/console/) out. Once you have learned this, this kind of errors won't happend again.

Comment: I've been programming for fun for about two years and never knew this. I've wasted so much time looking for stupid typos. Thanks!

Comment: FWIW, I would cache references to elements instead of querying the DOM  on every `keyup` event, i.e. `getElementById()`. I'd also not use inline event handlers and use `addEventListener()` instead, you know, separation of concerns and all. Here's [**an example**](https://jsfiddle.net/m38nua7u/) with those thoughts in mind and some other suggestions on how to reduce code repetition etc.

Comment: @John As you gain more reputation on StackOverflow you're awarded privileges, voting to close questions is one of them which requires 3k rep, see [**Privileges**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges).

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You got typo `documument.getElementById("name").style.color = "blue";` and `documument.getElementById("name").style.color = "red";`

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function count(x){      
                var size = x.length;    
                document.getElementById("show_length").innerHTML = size;

                if(size > 5){
                    //$("#name").css({"color":"blue"});
                    document.getElementById("name").style.color = "blue";                 
                } else {
                    //$("#name").css({"color":"red"});                  
                    document.getElementById("name").style.color = "red";  
                }   
            }

        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input type="text" name="name" id="name" autofocus maxlength="50" onkeyup="count(this.value)">
        <span id="show_length">0</span>/50
    </body>
</html>
```